# SQL SUM over multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Thanks to Gustav I'm a lot closer to the solution of my problem.

I'm using his code but it's not able to correctly sum.

[tblKasse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQyVZ.png)
[tblKursspielbuchung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqvjX.png)

I debugged my code and when I want to sum for 1 year I get this sql query: `"SELECT Datum, Sum(Kosten) FROM tblKursspielbuchung, tblKasse WHERE tblKursspielbuchung.Datum >= #2019/01/01# AND tblKursspielbuchung.Datum < #2020/01/01# GROUP BY Datum"`

For example I'm receiving 1460 instead of 730 which would be the correct answer. 
I can only think of having multiplt rows for Flights with the cost might be the problem. I'm having problems getting rid of them when I sum them. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how to use distinct or something similar in that situation. If nothing works I have to change the code so that I don't have the same cost in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your SQL like this:

```
int year = int.Parse(txtJahr.Text);

"SELECT Datum, Sum(Kosten) FROM tblKursspielbuchung, tblKasse WHERE tblKursspielbuchung.Datum >= #" + new DateTime(year, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND tblKursspielbuchung.Datum < #" + new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# GROUP BY Datum";
```

Comment: It's working. I just had to add    #" + before the second new DateTime

Comment: Because I have multiple entries I have to Group By Datum and FlightID.

Comment: Would you be sond kind to rewrite your code to work with month?  `"SELECT Datum, Sum(Kosten) FROM tblKasse, tblKursspielbuchung WHERE tblKursspielbuchung.Datum >= #" + new DateTime(year, month, 1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# AND tblKursspielbuchung.Datum < #" + new DateTime(year, month + 1, 1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# GROUP BY Datum";`          Doesn't work for me sadly. Using this code in Access I receive for every entry in the month as cost the cost of the year.

Comment: `"SELECT Datum, Sum(Kosten) FROM tblKursspielbuchung, tblKasse GROUP BY Datum";` Because month doesn't work I checked if year works when I remove the WHERE clause. It looks like the where clause is never used. Sum(Kosten) is instantly calculating the sum and after that isn't changed. Maybe I need to join this somewhere. Both tables are connected with FlightID.

Comment: Passing a month value will also work, so you be doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Often the issue with comparing dates is that the way you build the compare sets it up to compare as a string as opposed to comparing as a date.  I would do a date conversion before inserting the value into your select string.  If the compare is happening in MS ACCESS you will need to wrap the date with the # character - i.e. #date#

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, date constants have a special syntax.  I also strongly recommend `JOIN`.  I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT ks.Datum, Sum(Kosten)
FROM tblKursspielbuchung as ks INNER JOIN
     tblKasse as k
     ON ks.Datum = k.Datum
WHERE ks.Datum >= #01/01/2019# AND 'ks.Datum < #01/01/2010#
GROUP BY ks.Datum;
```

Comment: It's kind of working. I had to change your line 4 to ON ks.FlightID = k.FlightID because that's my foreign key where I can join them on. Strangely it's only giving me 880 as answer and not 1320. I have 6 lines with 220 and only 4 are added up. Could you check if in your line 6 ' is used correctly? Maybe that's the reason why some numbers are not added up.